# Detect focus loss for input element, not onBlur

Tags: javascript, html, dart, dart-html

I'm implementing an autocomplete/combobox in dart. I'm using two elements for this, a `<input type="text">` and a `<ul>` for the suggestions. I want to hide via css style `display: none` whenever the user leaves the input box. This works when using `onBlur`on the input element.

If the user tries to click an item in the `<ul>`, the input looses focus and the `<ul>`is hidden before the click event on the `<li>` is run.

```
_listElement = new UListElement();
_textElement = new TextInputElement()
  ..onBlur((e) => setDisplayToNone(_listElement)); // hide element
```

I noticed that a jQueryUI implementation does not have this issue and I can not figure out how they detect when to hide the suggestion box. see https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

What alternate way can i use to hide the `<ul>` without hiding it on `_textElement.onBlur`?

If it helps, the two elements are always wrapped by a `<div>`. I'm looking for a dart-only solution, although vanilla-js answers that I can rebuild in dart are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at events sequence:

1. input.focus
2. li.mousedown
3. input.blur
4. li.mouseup
5. li.click

So you might setup a flag variable, turn it up on `li.mousedown`, check it on `input.blur` and decide if you need to hide the list, and then turn it down on `li.click`